# How do I define a function whether x exists in the list in Python?

Tags: python, function

Define a function with following specs.

Takes two argments:
x: a scaler
l: a list
The function will check whether x exists in the list, and print out the results
if exists: yes
if not: no
For example:

func1(x = 12, l = [1,45,5,3])
Will produce

12 is no

```
def inList(x=12,l=[1,45,5,3]):
      for x in fuc1:
        if x in 1:
          print("value is in the list")
        else:
          print("value is not in the list")
```

Comment: `func1` is just `list.__contains__`, which is what defines the behavior of the `in` operator on lists. If you are supposed to be implementing it yourself, you probably don't want or need to use `in` anywhere in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

this can be a simple if statement

```
If x in i:
   print("It is here")
else:
   print("It is not here")
```

Comment: It can be an `if` statement but not an `If` statement.

Comment: My guess is that this is a homework assignment and therefore OP is meant to implement the built-in function themselves, not delegate to one that does all the work.

Answer (score 1):

just as simple:

```
def is_in_list(x, l):
    if x in l:
        print('in list')
        return
    else:
        print('not in list')
```

if you can't use `in` or you are trying to do it using loops then you can do so:

```
def is_in_list(x, l):
    for item in l:
        if(item == x):
            print('in list')
            return
    print('not in list')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
["No", "Yes"][x in l]
```

But, as @chepner commented, it seems you are expected to write your own implementation of `in`, so you should avoid using it in the first place.

What about looking at each item of `l` and testing whether is the same or not as your target. Do you know how to test if tow items have the same value?

(BTW, avoid using `l` as name. It looks like a number 1 in many editors)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the variable names up. Also, there is no need for a for loop in this case.

```
def inList(x=12,l=[1,45,5,3]):
    if x in l:
      print("value is in the list")
    else:
      print("value is not in the list")
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you:

```
MyList = [1,45,5,3]
x=12
def my_function(MyList , x):
# Print list
    print("Our List: ", MyList )

# Check if 'b' exists in the list or not
    if x in MyList:
        print(" value is in the list")
    else:
        print(" value is not in the list")
my_function(MyList, x)
```